# How do I fix this cp950 "illegal multibyte sequence" UnicodeDecodeError when reading a text file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

My teacher teach us that how to use "exec",but I got an error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'cp950' codec can't decode byte 0xe6 in position 1814: illegal multibyte sequence
```

I use:

```
exec(open("somefile.py").read())
```

how to fix this problem?

Comment: Have you tried exec(open("somefile.py","r").read()) instead?

Comment: That has nothing to do with `exec` and everything to do with the contents of `somefile.py`. What is in that file and how are you saving it? (As an aside: I don't know why any teacher would teach students about `exec` -- it's far more dangerous than useful, and unlikely to be what you want, even here.)

Comment: cp950? That's an interesting default encoding. What's the *actual* encoding `somefile.py` is encoded in?

Comment: @Gustavo: Why would that help? `r` is the default mode, and it's clearly the `read()` call failing, not the `open()` call.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Given this is presumably Python 3 source code, the likely encoding is UTF-8 (it's the standard encoding for Python 3 source code).

If that's the case, changing `open("somefile.py")` to `open("somefile.py", encoding="utf-8")` would specify the encoding explicitly, overriding the locale default, which should allow you to read it in correctly.

For idiomatic code, you'd also want to use a `with` statement (to guarantee deterministic closing of the file), making it:

```
with open("somefile.py", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    exec(f.read())
```